# Unable to add to an object into ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Why is the entires variable not defined If i made the arraylist called entires

```
public class College
{
    Student s = new Student();
    ArrayList <Student> entries;

    public College()
    {
        entries = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    public void add(Student s)
    {
        entires.add(s);
    }
}
```

Edited so ArrayList is available to the class?

Comment: You have defined your variable in the scope of the constructor. More the definition to instance level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have to define the `ArrayList` in the `class` scope like

```
public class College
{
    Student s = new Student();
    ArrayList <Student> entries;

    public College()
    {
        entries = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    public void add(Student s)
    {
        entries.add(s);
    }
}
```

so all you class can access you `ArrayList`

Comment: College.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  entires.add(s);
  ^
  symbol:   variable entires
  location: class College

Answer (score 1):

entries variable is defined locally.Define it global like below :

```
public class College
{
Student s = new Student();
ArrayList <Student> entries;

public College()
{
 entries = new ArrayList<Student>();
}

public void add(Student s)
{
    entires.add(s);
}
}
```

Comment: This is called a field, not a global variable.

Comment: @Njol thnks you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your entries variable is created locally in your constructor. it cannot be accessed in your method. Make you entries global.

```
public class College
{
Student s = new Student();
List <Student> entries;
public College()
{
 entries = new ArrayList<Student>();
}

public void add(Student s)
{
    entires.add(s);
}
}
```

Comment: College.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  entires.add(s);
  ^
  symbol:   variable entires
  location: class College

Still compiles same error

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `entries` variable as class member in order to access that variable in class methods.

It should be so:

```
public class College {
Student s = new Student();
ArrayList <Student> entries;

public College()
{
  entries = new ArrayList<Student>();
}

public void add(Student s)
{
    entires.add(s);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class College
  {

    private Student s = new Student();
    private List <Student> entries = ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Student s)
    {
       entires.add(s);
    }
  }
```

- Use the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface
- Java 7 supports [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) and you can simply write ArrayList<>
- You can define the list as a member instead of the constructor